# How to block creation of MySQL database with name that matches a certain pattern

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to configure MySQL to prevent creation of database schemas with a name that match a certain condition? Ideally, I want to prevent creation with names that match a pattern, but if there is a solution to block names that *do not* match a pattern I think I can make that work too. For example, I want to block the creation of schemas with names starting with a number.

Comment: MsSQL meaning...MySQL?

Comment: Who's creating tables on your system other than a DBA? Allowing access to random people sounds **extremely risky and ill-advised** even with some kind of "sanity check" like this in place.

Comment: @tadman yes. MySQL. Was a typo thanks.

Comment: @tadman, this is a development database and the schemas are created automatically based on developer's hostname. In some cases, developers hostname are missing and the db will be created with an IP address. I want the db creating to fail so the developer will remember to fix the missing hostname issue.

Comment: If there is no easy way to do this on db level, I'll just just ask the people who maintain the  the automated code that invokes the schema creation to put a condition there.

Comment: Doing it on the DB level is something that would be Surprising (as in violating the *Principle of Least Surprise*) to discover when trying to create a table, as one does when developing, and being told "No". I'd recommend that whatever tool generates these tables does so with whatever rules you have in mind, and errors out if the names generated are violating that rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you [grant the CREATE privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create) to a given user, they can create tables or schemas. There's no way to filter them by the naming convention.

You could create a stored procedure that accepts a string argument. Then check the string against a regular expression, and if it's okay, then use that string in a prepared statement.

This way you can grant the CREATE privilege to the owner of the procedure, and then allow users to call the procedure.

If you don't want to use a stored procedure, then perhaps implement an API to do it.